# How use a map inside a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on a project that demands i create a map inside a fragment because i was already using the navigation component. I will have to manipulate this map, inserting pins, open map on user location and others stuff.

I was using [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentatin/android-sdk/start#None-kotlin) as reference but i am getting a null pointer exception on supportFragmentManager.

So my question is, how i can create and manipulate a map inside a fragment?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

This is how i put the documentation code into a fragment.

```
private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        binding = FragmentClientOrdersBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)

        val mapFragment = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        }

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        mMap = googleMap!!
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions()
            .position(sydney)
            .title("Marker in Sydney"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for now i user childFragmentManager and it worked